# numpy linalg.solve equation

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Is there a way to solve this equation in python where the solution is one of the operands in `np.linalg.solve`?

```py
A = np.linalg.solve(B.T, np.dot(A,B).T).T
```

`A` (quantum gate) and `B` (rho before) are 2d 4x4 complex numpy arrays, and B is known. What I'm trying to find is the inverse of quantum rho evolve, which is done (`C` rho after) and I want to find `A` from `B` and `C`.

```py
C = np.dot(np.dot(A, B), np.conjugate(A.T))
```

#Based on if **C = np.dot(A,B)** then **A= np.linalg.solve(B.T, C.T).T**
I end with this equation:

```
mygate = np.linalg.solve(rhobefore.T,(np.linalg.solve((np.conjugate(gate.T)).T, rhoafter.T).T).T).T
```

where mygate and gate matrices must be the same(or equivalent). So I ask if there is a any method in python to solve it, like sympy,

Comment: Since `A` is undefined, you'll need to rewrite the problem. Python will not know what `A` is on the right-hand side.

Comment: I've written your problem out on paper and it does not make sense. Well, I guess it does make sense, but there are infinitely many solutions and the problem doesn't have any meaning. Your problem written out is `A = (inv(B)'(AB)')'` (where the ' means transpose). Working through it (`(AB)' = B'A'` -> `inv(B)'B'A' = A'` -> `A = (A')'`) you end up with `A=A`, which is always true.

Comment: I rewritted the question to clarify the problem,

Comment: It is still not clear. Just state your knowns and unknowns and their respective shapes.

Comment: (1) Your bolded equation doesn't match the equation below it (missing conjugate). (2) If we do go by just the bolded equation, it is still the same equation as before and has the same shortcoming I've already mentioned.